# I can't get my content centered vertically in the rightbox

Tags: html, css

I have a website from two sides, left and right. But I can't get the right box's content centered in the right box.

I can't really change the container css because then the whole site will collapse, because the site is build with Jquery. But now I can't get my content box centered vertically and horizontally in the RIGHT box.

The jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndEXN/

**HTML**

```
<!-- LEFT -->
<div id="left">
<div id="t_content">
<div id="t_container">

<div id="t1_b1">Random title I</div>
<div id="t1_b2">Random text I</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- RIGHT -->
<div id="right">
<div id="f_content">
<div id="f_container">

<div id="f1_b1">Random title II</div>
<div id="f1_b2">Random text II</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #6e0e10;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    overflow:hidden
}
#t_container {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0;
    margin:auto; 
    height:120px; 
    width:600px;
}
#t1_b1 {
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.95;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 105px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 247px;
}
#t1_b2 {
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.95;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#t_content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
}
#right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #130e6e;
    background-position: right;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#f_container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    height:120px; 
    width:600px;
}
#f1_b1 {
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.95;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 105px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 247px;
}
#f1_b2 {
    background: #000000;
    opacity: 0.95;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#f_content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: is thee any reason why you are absolutely positioning things and then having fixed widths inside your relative width containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add bottom: 0; and top:0; to your #f_container

```
#f_container {
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
height:120px; 
width:600px;
bottom:0;
top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding-top:280px;` in #f_container css 
@Edit demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ndEXN/2/

Comment: Now the box is standing almost in the middle but on a smaller screen or a bigger screen it isn't in the middle. So this isn't a responsive solution. It need to be centered, even on small or big screens..

Answer (score 0):

For your right container `#f_content` give it `position:absolute;`

and for your `#f_container` give it

```
top:50%; 
position:relative;
```

Check this out 
http://jsfiddle.net/ndEXN/4/

I hope this can help 
Also I think this might help you to understand

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score -1):

Use `Vertical-align:middle;` on your right div css. it should work

Comment: Vertical-align is for within a table cell.